# Why am i being told to use <li> the way shown below <<<<

Tags: html

I cant seem to find a straight answer on any website really.

As you can see on line 2 `<li>` is all alone with no `</li>` after louis
Im being told to close it toward the end, i don't get it sadly.

Line 2 and the second from the bottem are what I'm talking about.

```
<ul>
    <li> Louis <<<<
        <ol>
            <li> Louis </li>
            <li> Louis </li>
            <ul>
                <li> Louis </li>
                <li> Louis </li>
                <ol>
                    <li> Louis </li>
                    <li> Louis </li>
                </ol>
            </ul>
        </ol>
    </li> <<<<
</ul>
```

Comment: That would be a nested `ol` (ordered list) inside the `li` (list item) of the parent `ul` (unordered list)

Answer (score 5):

I have formatted your code to make more clear what is going on. All that is happening is that the lists are nested.

Please note, however, that the code you have posted is not actually valid HTML. [`UL` and `OL` elements can only have `LI` elements as children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul). Nesting a `UL` directly inside an `OL` or vice versa is not valid syntax.

Most likely, you are trying to include the `UL` and `OL` elements inside `LI` elements, like this:

```
<ul>
    <li> Louis
        <ol>
            <li> Louis </li>
            <li> Louis
                <ul>
                    <li> Louis </li>
                    <li> Louis
                        <ol>
                            <li> Louis </li>
                            <li> Louis </li>
                        </ol>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Which renders like this:

- Louis

  1. Louis
  2. Louis

     - Louis
     - Louis

       1. Louis
       2. Louis

One more little note: if you try to include `<<<<` in your HTML, it will break. I assume those were just for illustration in your question. If you want to output a literal `<` in HTML, use `&lt;`.